# Titanium 3.5 and Updating Modules for 64 bit architecture - except I am not using any modules

Tags: titanium

I am endeavoring to update my apps for use with iOS8 and apples newest devices.  The previous build worked flawlessly for iOS7.

Already I am bumping up against a wall trying to bring things up to speed for 64 bit architecture.  I am receiving an error which reads:

```
[ERROR] :  Script Error Couldn't find module: /Users/.../Config for architecture: i386
```

Strangely the error above says i386 on the most recent launch of the app in the simulator, but all previous errors listed x86.

The file in question isn't a module, but rather a commonJS file that is required by the page which displays the error.  I have searched high and low but cannot find any documentation for how to bring this document up to speed.

The document itself is fairly basic:

```
module.exports = {
    "isSimulator" : true,   
    "Locations" : "/data/locations.json",
    "GPS_Purpose" : "Fin stuff",
    "GoogleMapAPIKey" : "xxyyzz",
    "MapZoom" : 13,
    "MapType" : "ROADMAP",
    "use_miles" : true,

    "images" : {
        "autoScroll" : true,
        "backgroundColor" : "#000",
        "nav" : {
            "selectedColor" : "#000",
            "color" : "#eee",
            "border" : false,
            "borderColor" : "#000",
            "backgroundColor" : "transparent",
            "displayAsBlocks" : true
        }
    },
};
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: Of course the difference in errors between i386 and x86_64 was because I was simulating in different devices (5 vs 6 Plus).